# Custom UITableViewCell, table won't scroll to the bottom

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I need to build an Airbnb-like table index for displaying real estate, for which I customised a prototype UITableViewCell with a height of 200 and two custom Labels (created using Storyboard) and a background image (added programmatically). All this was laid over a TableViewController added using Storyboard.

The data is being fetched from a JSON file and contains 10 items. But in the iPhone simulator (4-inch),

a) It won't scroll beyond the first three items. I can see only the top half of the third item. How do I make it scroll all the 10 items right to the bottom of the last item?

b) The table overlaps the top iPhone status bar (with battery and network status). The storyboard doesn't allow resizing of the TableView to exclude any padding from the top or bottom. How can I leave some padding from the top and the bottom of the table?

Here is my **cellForRowAtIndexPath** from **MainViewcontroller.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
RealEstateTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


RealEstate *estates = [self.allEstate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched];



cell.titleLabel.text=estates.title;

cell.infoLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ | %@",[properties formattedDate], [estates organiser]];


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:estates.photoURL];

 NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

[cell.backgroundView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];


return cell;
}
```

Comment: post your relevant code

Comment: I know it may be too late, but for my own curiosity how are you scrolling over your tableview, are you using two finger gesture on ios simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure , you added the below `UITableView` delegate method :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 200;
}
```

For second case, you can try with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18103727/434898).

Comment: Thanks, this reveals the entire table cell. But I still can't scroll beyond 3 items. Anything else I'm doing wrong? (see my code added to the original post).

Comment: @bombaypundit then try with increasing the size of TableView i.e something to (320,420);, may be that could work out. Are you seeing the full tableView OR may be you could post app screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this qualifies as a resolution to this question, but the app runs alright without any of the aforementioned problems on an actual iPhone. For now I'm doing all the further building and testing on an iPhone. I will come back to the simulator at the very end and hopefully it should be running there too.